# Android Grideview selected Item using onTouch

Tags: android, gridview

I am working on Calendar with gridview ,Rightnow I have implemented gesture listener for left and right swipe,All are working fine , But using onsingletapconfirmed i could not able to get the position of the selected item in the griview. I tried with the below code

int j = gridview.pointToPosition((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());

Please help to me solve the problem.

Thanks and Regards,
Venkatesan.R